# Intuition behind the Riesz transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Define the Riesz transform in singular integral form

\begin{equation*}
R_jf(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\pi^{\frac{-(n+1)}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})\int_{|y|>\epsilon}\frac{y_jf(x-y)}{|y|^{n+1}}dy. 
\end{equation*}

I know it is a generalisation of the Hilbert transform. They are clearly of the same form, both p.v integrals, convolution operators, except the Riesz transforms is in a generalised vectorial form for the $j^{th}$ component. What about the constants in front of the integral? Any thoughts or comments are welcome.

Comment: The constant is related to the volume of the sphere...

Comment: Does that mean we are integrating over the sphere?

Comment: Plainly, no, we are not integrating over the sphere! You yourself typed the domain of the integral...

Comment: I did (by definition), but why  is there this relation to the volume of the sphere?

Comment: Do you have any intuition to explain the constant $1/\pi$ appearing in from of the Hilbert transform? Exactly the same intuition applies here (that $\pi$ is half the length of the unit circle, just as the constant here is $1/v$ with $v$ half the volume of the $n$-sphere). Now, if you do not have any intuition about that $1/\pi$, then you should be asking about that, really :-)

Comment: Ah, I just got it! Thanks :)